# How to disable tty1 and backlight using Arch Linux

Tags: display, x-server, xrdp, rdesktop

I have a laptop which I want to use only remotely via rdp (xvnc server). I have setup rdp successfully. As I only use the laptop remotely, I want to disable it's display. To do that, I have already disabled lightdm. However, now at boot it shows:

```
Antergos Linux 4.14.15-1-ARCH (tty1)

simon login:
```

I want to disable this display. However, I have no idea how to. I've tried:

```
xset dpms force off
```

but that only gives an error that the display cannot be found. Is x server even still running? If so, how do I disable it and blank the screen (and disable the laptop backlight)?

Comment: I found out that the command `systemctl stop getty@tty1` disables the tty1, but the backlight of the laptop stays on and it stills displays a flashing underscore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're seeing a login prompt on `tty1`, the local X server has been stopped and the virtual console is in text mode, acting as a terminal emulator. (The `xvnc` is a separate, "virtual display" X server for incoming VNC/RDP connections. It does not deal with physical display, keyboard or mouse at all.)

To force disable it, you need the `setterm` command:

```
setterm --blank force
```

But if you plan to run it remotely or from a script, you'll need to use it in a bit longer form:

```
setterm --blank force --term linux </dev/tty1
```

In case you need to re-enable:

```
setterm --blank poke --term linux </dev/tty1
```

Yes, the redirection is non-intuitive; it's the same special case as with the `stty` command.

With older versions of `setterm`, you may have to use `>/dev/tty1` instead.

Comment: I've got same situation, but this solution didn't work for me. When I do `setterm --blank force --term linux >/dev/tty1` from root, I got an error message `setterm: cannot force blank: Inappropriate ioctl for device`. And if I add `</dev/tty1` then I got no error but no result - screen does not blank.

Comment: You probably have a local X server still running. The original poster had it already disabled. Or maybe you're just switched away from virtual console #1 for some reason?

Comment: No, X server is not running on that machine. And I didn't switch from console #1 - actually, that is a Raspberry PI attached to TV but without any keyboard. I run all commands via SSH.

Comment: Interesting observation: when I run (in regular terminal) `setterm --blank 1 | hexdump -C`, I see that it outputs `<ESC>[9;1]`. But if I run it with `--blank force` or `--blank poke`, it doesn't output anything. That means that redirection (`... > /dev/tty1`) is meaningless, right?

Comment: Here is what I managed to find out: for `--blank {poke,force}`, `setterm` uses `ioctl`. And it uses the *input* tty, not *output*. After I enabled general blanking by adding `consoleblank=600` parameter to kernel command line and rebooted system, the following works for me (over ssh): `sudo sh -c 'setterm --term linux -blank force < /dev/tty1'`

Comment: Looks like the current version of `setterm` is different from what I had back when I wrote that, since I tested those commands and verified that they worked. Yet, with the current version, I need to use the input tty too. `setterm --version` says `setterm from util-linux 2.92.2` for me; is yours the same?

Comment: Mine is `setterm from util-linux 2.33.1`.